# Вытащить номера пользователей в массив с функции

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу вытащить номера всех рефералов Пользователя, и номера их рефералов.
Через `print_r` все выводится, но надо вытащить массив.

```
function refPhone($id, $phone){
    global $wpdb;

    // Получаем список рефералов текущего пользователя
    $query_user_referrals = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_dashboard_users` WHERE user_partner_phone = $phone" );
    // Количество рефералов
    $referals_count = $query_user_referrals ? count($query_user_referrals) : "0";

    // Если рефералы есть
    if($referals_count > 0){

        // Перебор рефералов
        foreach($query_user_referrals as $query_user_referral){
            // Id реферала
            $ref_id = $query_user_referral->id;
            // Телефон реферала
            $ref_phone = $query_user_referral->user_phone;

            // Выводим телефон
            print_r($ref_phone)

            // Применяем функцию на рефералов реферала
            refPhone($ref_id, $ref_phone);       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит вытащить массив?

Comment: $arr[]=$ref_phone; вставь после принтр и потом после функции выведи print_r($arr);

Answer (score 0):

```
function refPhone($id, $phone){
    global $wpdb;

    // Получаем список рефералов текущего пользователя
    $query_user_referrals = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_dashboard_users` WHERE user_partner_phone = $phone" );
    // Количество рефералов
    $referals_count = $query_user_referrals ? count($query_user_referrals) : "0";

    // Если рефералы есть
    if($referals_count > 0){

        // Перебор рефералов
        $userPhones = [];
        foreach($query_user_referrals as $query_user_referral){
            // Id реферала
            $ref_id = $query_user_referral->id;
            // Телефон реферала
            $ref_phone = $query_user_referral->user_phone;


            $userPhones[$query_user_referral->id] = $query_user_referral->user_phone;


            // Применяем функцию на рефералов реферала
            refPhone($ref_id, $ref_phone);       
        }

        foreach($userPhones as $userId => $userPhone) {
            echo 'Юзер: ' . $userId . ' Телефон: ' . $userPhone;
        }
    }
}
```